# The relation between this series and infinitely integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequence-of-function

By directly computing, I find that $$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{i-1}}{1+2^{2^i}}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{x-1}}{1+2^{2^x}}dx,$$ but why is there such a coincidence?

Comment: This looks like the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), just with a different function.

Comment: Did you use Mathematica to compute this result? Your question is interesting, but it is missing a bit of detail.

Comment: Why don't you show your direct computation?

Comment: I have computed both sides RHS is $\frac{\pi}{4\ln 2}$ and LHS equals to it numerically.

Comment: @Z Ahmed You may want to check your computation: the correct value is $\frac1{\ln 4}$ (RHS: Wolfram Alpha, LHS: easy telescoping sum and elementary limit).

Comment: Maybe you can see the [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula). For the time being, ${\tt Mathematica}$ was unable to compute the Fourier Transform.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Post your answer, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I fail to see how the LHS telescopes. Can you give a hint about the derivation?

Comment: @FelixMarin The Fourier transform evaluates to an $\eta$ function, so the Poisson summation formula is not directly applicable.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg $$\frac{2^{i-1}}{x^{2^1}+1}=\frac{2^{i-1}}{x^{2^i}-1}-\frac{2^i}{x^{2^{i+1}}-1}$$